# Get Lat/Long (geotag) from picasa images with picasa API with PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework, picasa

I have looked everywhere to try and get the answer to this simple task to no avail.

I just need to get the lat/long (geotag) from an image.  The docs give an example of how to update the GmlPos in the GeoRssWhere. ( http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/docs/1.0/developers_guide_php.html )  But how do you just retrieve that info?

I'v tried the below, but I think i'v got something wrong.

```
  $where = new Zend_Gdata_Geo_Extension_GeoRssWhere();
  $georeff = $where->point;
```

can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

The Picasa API returns entities as `Zend_Gdata_Photos_PhotoEntry`

You can use `getGeoRssWhere()` to get the geo data:

```
$geo = $photo->getGeoRssWhere();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a great example getting geotag to display photos on a map like I wanted to do. http://picasaphpworkshop.googlecode.com/svn-history/r11/trunk/workshop.php

The part I couldn't figure out was the $where->getPoint()->getPos();  after getting the georsshwere.

```
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Media_Extension_MediaKeywords');
 Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Geo_Extension_GeoRssWhere');
 Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Geo_Extension_GmlPos');
 Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Geo_Extension_GmlPoint');
 Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Photos_PhotoEntry');


 $picasa = new Zend_Gdata_Photos();
 $query = $picasa->newAlbumQuery();
 $query->setUser('user@gmail.com');
 $query->setAlbumName('MyAlbumNameFromURL');
 $feed = $picasa->getAlbumFeed($query);

 foreach($feed as $num => $photoEntry){

           $where = $photoEntry->getGeoRssWhere();
            $lat = $where->getPoint()->getPos();
            //$lat = split(" ", $lat); // Split out the space-separated lat

 }


echo "GeoReff: " . $lat . "<br />\n";
```